# Javascript Browser Detect with IE 11

Tags: javascript, browser-detection, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to fix some javascript code that I am currently using on a website - which was working perfectly until IE 11 came along. The script is used to first detect the type of browser used then autofills the name of a file (like a JPEG or PDF) into a specified textfield, after the file has been uploaded to the site. However I am not the original author of this script and I am very unfamiliar with Javascript. I have searched everywhere for a solution and so far have found nothing to help me with this problem. Hoping someone can help. Here is the current code:

```
<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value(){
    BrowserDetect.init();
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Explorer'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
BrowserDetect.init();
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Explorer'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Safari'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Chrome'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Opera'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
 if(BrowserDetect.browser=='Firefox'){
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }
}
function closeChildWindow(){
    self.close();   
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're testing for browser type? Did you strip out any code? That said, you could just reduce everything down to 3 lines since every if is reusing the same code. Not sure why Explorer is being tested twice, either.

Comment: All branches look the same...

Comment: Just to add, it seems that BrowserDetect is from a very old (circa 2008) version of MooTools so it could be the outdated framework amongst other things.

Comment: Not sure, again I am not the original author of this code and know nothing about Javascript, please excuse my ignorance. Oops, the Explorer twice markup was my fault when placing the text online (my bad), but thank you for your comments, however like I said, I know nothing when it comes to Javascript so I would need to see an example of what it should look like based on your suggestions, maybe more simplified but still performing the same function. Can any one help with that?

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about your comments about browser detection, I decided to play with the code a little and discovered that it's not needed and works great now. Thanks Eric Barber for your help in pointing me in the right direction! Here is the amended code:

```
<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value(){
    {
    var str=document.formSmallPhoto.file1.value;
    var index=str.lastIndexOf("\\");    
    opener.document.form1.small_photo.value = str.substring(index+1);   
 }


}
function closeChildWindow(){
    self.close();   
}   
</script>
```